# Get AADObject Id of the user @mentioned to the Microsoft Teams Bot

Tags: azure, botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service, microsoft-graph-teams

I am developing a Microsoft Teams bot using Azure Bot service, I have a use case where I need fetch the @mentioned users AAD object Id and use this Id to get other enterprises specific user information.
I have tried to use turnContext object's, `GetMentions()` API which returns [Channel Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.schema.channelaccount?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable) object, however, the AAD Object property of channel account is empty, though it has an Id property which I believe corresponds to the Bot [Service channel's (Microsoft Teams)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-resources-identifiers-guide?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) user.

Given my research, could someone please let me know how to fetch the users AAD object Id or point me to the right documentation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the id of the user using [Bot Context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-context) using the id you receive from GetMentions(29:id). Please try this code and let us know if you face any issues:

```
  private static async Task<string> GetUserEmailId(Activity activity, string id)
    {
        var teamId = context.Activity.GetChannelData<TeamsChannelData>().Team.Id;
        ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
        var members1 = await connector.Conversations.GetConversationMembersAsync(teamId);
        var mem = members1.Where(m => m.Id == id).First().AsTeamsChannelAccount().ObjectId;
        return mem;
    }
```

Comment: Hi Gousia, This was a good lead, however, it dint work for me, instead I used this
var members = await TeamsInfo.GetMembersAsync(turnContext, cancellationToken);